# How to upload documents programmatically to IBM Knowledge Studio?

Tags: watson-knowledge-studio

I currently generate every hour the latest news from some some sites. I can't find any way to upload the documents to annotate via API. Is it possible to do it via some script?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Watson Knowledge Studio doesn't provide REST API so far. There has been a feature request to support API. Please vote on the request if you want.
https://ibm-data-and-ai.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WKS-I-26